# Speller - unloading a trie - function doesn´t work properly

Tags: c, recursion, cs50, trie

I am trying to free a trie, but I can still see a lot of used memory after running valgrind. Could someone point me in the right direction? What could I change? I tried to draw it on paper and logically it makes sense to me, but obviously it doesn´t work properly. Thank you for any inputs!

```
bool destroy(node *tmp)
{
     // Going through all the children nodes
    for (int i = 0, number = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // If children node is not NULL, destroy it (recursion)
        if (tmp->children[i] != 0)
        {
            return destroy(tmp->children[i]);
        }
    }

    // At this point all the children nodes should be NULL
    // Free current node
    free(tmp);
    return true;
}
```

```
valgrind output:
==5374== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5374==     in use at exit: 3,808 bytes in 17 blocks
==5374==   total heap usage: 23 allocs, 6 frees, 14,352 bytes allocated
```

Comment: Remove the `return` from the recursive call to `destroy`.  And I’m not clear why the function is returning a value at all as it only ever returns `true`.   Make it into a function returning `void`.

Comment: Your algorithm was great. The errors were just syntactical. Cheers! you'll do great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supppose it should be

```
if (tmp -> children[j] != NULL)
{
  destroy(tmp -> children[j]);
}
```

For you are trying to check for NULL condition.

You should change it to a void function so that recursion can occur freely

---

Comment: This is correct: once you release a child (together with its subtree, hopefully) you should not return, but rather you want to release all remaining children of `tmp`, too, as well as `tmp` itself!

Comment: Recursion can occur regardless of the return type.  However, a function that always returns the same value may as well not return anything.  Though, funnily enough, only yesterday, I had to leave a function that always returns success as a function returning an `int` because it was used in an array of function pointers and therefore had to match the type of the other functions in the array.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented. I can see my mistake now. I changed the return type to void, since there is no point for the function to return anything and deleted return before calling the function for recursion. Now it frees all the nodes.